# Having trouble to read the file in DBFS

Tags: azure, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2, databricks-unity-catalog

Im having some issues to read the the file which is stored in `DBFS`. it was not a problem before but i made some modification to my workspace and storage account. Late me list them:

1. I wanted to enable the Unity catalog and created the metastore, then assiged that metastore to my workspace.
2. Then I Created storage credentials, and external locations ( with the access connector having a storage blob data contributor role on my storage account.
3. I also changed my cluster from `No isolation shared` to `shared access mode` which supports the unity catalog.

Beofre that there was onlu mounting done to the storage account.

Below is my code where Im trying to set the directory if it does not exits and then read the file from that directory. Yous the functions defined in the class.

```
  class gpg_encryption(gnupg.GPG):

  asc_key_path = '/dbfs/keys/'
 
  def __init__(self):
    self.gpg = gnupg.GPG()
    self.gpg.encoding = 'utf-8'
    self.create_key_path_dir()
   
  def create_key_path_dir(self):
    """
    Creates a folder to store keyfiles.
    """
    if not os.path.exists(self.asc_key_path):
      os.makedirs(self.asc_key_path)
     
  def create_asc_keyfile(self, keyfile_name, key):
    """
    Write key as armored ASCII
    """
    with open(self.asc_key_path + keyfile_name + '.asc', 'w') as f:
      f.write(key)
```

problem occures when check if the current directory exits or no, It wants me to change the path from `/dbfs/keys/` to `dbfs:/keys`. After changeing that it has the prblem to open that with that path and asking me to change back to `/dbfs/keys/`.

Could you please help in fixing this and some documentation would be great, as Im reading some documentation myself and I got little bit confused too.

Comment: “*It wants me to change the path from /dbfs/keys/ to dbfs:/keys. After changeing that it has the prblem to open that with that path and asking me to change back to /dbfs/keys/.*” To what does “*it*” in this context refer to, and how did “*it*” communicate this message to you? If this is based on an error message, you should include its text verbatim in your question. [ask]

Comment: @esqew no its not, the error message is that `operation not supported` and point to `os.makedirs(self.asc_key_path)` this line.  When i do `dbutils.fs.ls('/dbfs/keys')`  error message is  `no such file or directory` but the Spark Tip suggesting me to use `dbfs:` instead of `/dbfs`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are working in a Databricks context, such as reading through Spark or listing using `dbutils`, you need to use the URI schema way: `protocol:/path_to_data`.

Example:

1. `dbfs:/tmp/sample.csv` for accessing a file in `dbfs`
2. `file:/tmp/demo.csv` for accessing a file from the root location
3. `wasbs://containername@accountname.blob.core.windows.net`
4. `abfss://filesystemname@accountname.dfs.core.windows.net`

When it comes to a local or Python context, you need to access files from the root location with **POSIX-style paths** and prefix the path with `/`.

Example:

1. `/dbfs/...` for accessing a file in `dbfs`
2. `/Workspace/...` for accessing a file in `Workspace`

Usually, Python modules can only use POSIX-style paths.

Below, you can see it is creating folders in different contexts.

[image]

To learn more about working with files in Databricks, refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/files/).